# how to adjust height of a subplot?

Tags: matlab, subplot

I have two subplots and I need to have the first subplot bigger in size than the second subplot, as the second subplot is a triggering Signal. I have adjusted the size and reduced the gap between the subplots as well. But the Problem is that when i try to increase the height of the first subplot, it goes out of the figure. I have tried alot but cant find a solution. Below is the code:

```
figure

x = (Messwerte.mste_w.value);
x = x';
%calculates the integral for all the values
t = cumtrapz(x);
subplot(9,1,1);
%plotting mste_w and its integral together
[ax,h1,h2] = plotyy(Messwerte.(Messwerte.mste_w.time),...
Messwerte.mste_w.value,Messwerte.(Messwerte.mste_w.time),t,@area,@plot);

set(h1, 'FaceColor', 'g','LineWidth', 2);
set(h2, 'LineWidth', 2);
set(gca,'ButtonDownFcn','selectmoveresize');
set(gcf,'WindowButtonDownFcn','selectmoveresize');
A = get(gca,'position');
A_diff = 1.5*A(4);             
A(4) = A(4) + A_diff;
A(2) = A(2)-0.15*A(2) ;
set(gca,'position',A);
%set(ax(1),'xtick',[0:500:2000])
set(ax(1),'ylim',[0 7],'ytick',[0:1:7])
%set(ax(2),'xtick',[0:500:2000])
set(ax(2),'ylim',[0 70000],'ytick',[0:10000:70000])
axes(ax(1)); ylabel('mste-w','color','k');
axes(ax(2)); ylabel('Spülvolumen in miliLiter');
%xlabel('time[s]')
set(ax(1),'YColor', 'k');
set(ax(2),'YColor', 'k');
grid on
% title('FTP75 AKB beladen')


subplot(9,1,2);
plot(Messwerte.(Messwerte.B_te.time),Messwerte.B_te.value);
A = get(gca,'position');

% A(1,4) = 2*A(1,4) / 3 ;             % reduce the height by one third
% A(1,2) = A(1,2) - 0.1*A(1,4);         % change the vertical position

A_diff = A(4)/3;
A(4)=A(4)-A_diff;
A(2)=A(2)-0.5*A_diff;
set(gca,'position',A);
area(Messwerte.(Messwerte.B_te.time),Messwerte.B_te.value,...
    'FaceColor','g');
set(gca,'xtick',[0:500:2000]);
set(gca,'ytick',[]);
ylabel('B-te');
```

Answer (score 1):

So, as I understand it, you have two subplots, together taking up 2/9ths of the height of the figure, and you would like to decrease the size of the second to 2/3 of the default, and increase the size of the first to 4/3 of the default.

So we want the first subplot to be (4/3) x (1/9) = 4/27 of the height, and the second to be (2/3) x (1/9) = 2/27 of the height. The easiest way to do this is this is:

```
subplot(27,1,1:4);
% plot first figure
subplot(27,1,5:6);
% plot second figure
```